# Nexus 5 static buzzing of speaker

Tags: nexus-5, speaker

My Nexus 5 has an annoying buzzing sound when it is set on low volumes. Any application using the speaker produces this, but when I get a call the ringtone doesn't buzz at all.

So I came to the conclusion that the speaker IS NOT physically broken.

When I plug in earphones and run an application the sound is working fine as well.

What is going wrong and how I can fix this? Should I try asking Google directly?

Comment: looks like its a feature. sacrificed the soundquality to secure the cheap price.